# Are there any caveats to log messages in custom exception constructor?

Tags: python, exception

Everytime I catch the exception I want to log something about it, so it is wise to put it inside the Exception constructor? Am I digging my own grave here?

```
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class GatewayException(Exception):
    message = None

    def __init__(self, message, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GatewayException, self).__init__(message)
        self.message = message
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        logger.error(message)
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            logger.error("{} : {}".format(key, value))
```

Comment: keep in mind it's entirely possible to _create_ an exception and never _raise_ it.  also, this way, you can't preserve the traceback with `logger.exception()`.

Comment: True, I vaguely remember someone mentioned it, 99% of the time it is created to be raised, but thanks for raising this point.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend leaving out the `logger` call in the `GatewayException` class itself.

The code as you've currently written it uses a *global* `logger` object, which violates encapsulation and *could* be problematic if you want to use the logger elsewhere in assorted classes/modules/etc.

To solve that issue, you *could* pass the `logger` to the `GatewayException` constructor, but what if you don't actually want to log something at a particular `except` point?

To allow for that possibility, if you encapsulate the message within the exception, and leave out the `logger` call you can choose at the `except` point whether to log the error or not, using the local `logger` object, whatever that may be.

To ensure the formatting is consistent, you can centralize formatting/output code into a `__str__` function which references `class` members from within.

Comment: er, module-level loggers are extremely common.  how on earth does this violate encapsulation of anything?

Comment: Just b/c mod-level loggers are common doesn't mean it doesn't violate encapsulation. If you're only going to use it in that 1 module, it's not a big deal, but if you want to use it in other modules, or w/ diff. loggers, which is certainly possible for many different types of exceptions, then IMO it would be better to either pass the logger as an arg to the constructor or call it at the `except` point. It certainly violates, to some extent, the general notion of encapsulation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29), though it may not matter for all cases.